# Most efficient algorithm to parse and compare string keys in java

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, key, compare

I have the following `Set<String>` objects.

```
 "A_B_C_D_E_F_G",
 "A_B_C_D_E_X_G",
 "A_B_C_D_E_Z_G",
 "A_B_C_X_Y_F_G",
 "P_B_C_D_E_F_G",
 "A_C_N_D_E_F_G"
 ... and 10,000 more
```

Each String is a underscore separated list of unique ids. So to help you understand you can think of each string like this:

```
 String[] uniqueIds = string.split("_");
```

What I want to do is put each String into a `Collection<String>` where the Strings are grouped together if only one uniqueId is different, and the difference occurs in the same 'column'.

So if we looped through the `Set<String>` objects in the example shown above the following groupings would occur

```
Group1
 "A_B_C_D_E_F_G",
 "A_B_C_D_E_X_G", (because X is different than F)
 "A_B_C_D_E_Z_G", (because Z is different than F, and because Z and X are 
                   in the same column)

Group2
 "P_B_C_D_E_F_G", (because P is different than A, and is not the same column as 
                   in Group1)

Group3
 "A_B_C_X_Y_F_G", (because X is different than D, and is not the same column as 
                   in Group1 or Group2)
                  (because Y is different than E, and is not the same column as 
                   in Group1 or Group2)
Group4
 "A_C_N_D_E_F_G", (because C is different than B, and is not the same column as 
                   in Group1 or Group2 or Group 3)
                  (because N is different than C, and is not the same column as 
                   in Group1 or Group2 or Group 3)
```

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way of creating these groupings.

My initial guess would be to start with an empty `Map<someKey,Collection<String>>`.

Then loop through the `Set<String>`, split each String into a uniqueId array and go through the Map looking for `someKey` which would would tell if that String belongs in the current collection, or goes into a new collection with a different `someKey`.  Defining what `someKey` is may be a bit tricky...maybe it would be a underscore separated list of the column numbers which values that have changed since the first String?

Since each String contains a lot of `uniqueIds` and the `Set<String>` size can be 10,000 it would seem that this algorithm can get slow quick.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

UPDATE:::

There are cases where a String can fit into more than 1 group.  If that is the case, it would just be placed into the first available group that meets the criteria.

Comment: Why is "A_B_C_D_E_F_G" in group one vs group two? Would it be legal in both or is the shown solution the only correct solution?

Comment: I would recommend you use a Compressed Trie or Tree. It might be sparse, but it fits your problem.

Comment: very complex algorthms. for example the next value is P_B_C_X_Y_F_G
is should be in group 2 or not ?

Comment: @Sign - It could be in either group.  The easiest way to deal with that would be to stick it in the first available group that it comes across.

Comment: In the case of different possibilities of grouping, is there a preference (fewer groups, smaller groups, etc)?

Say the strings are `s1 = A_B_C_D, s2 = A_P_C_D, s3 = A_B_X_D, s4 = A_P_C_Z`. Following a sequential reasoning we'd have groups `{s1,s2}, {s3}, {s4}` but it could have been `{s1,s3},{s2,s4}`.

Comment: @madth3 - fewer groups would be desired if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have to say I'm not an algorithm expert.
But maybe you should try taking a look at
1) The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena - he has many solutions for common problem
2) Using a Tree where letters are the Node-values. Maybe you could somehow try a suffix tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree The article says it is popular for many string operations. If you take a look at the "Applications" section in the article it really seems to fit :) And it runs in linear time.

To find the group a string belongs to, you can simply walk along the tree and look up until which degree a string matches and where it doesn't. (My intention)

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting read!  I'll look more into it and compare against any other ideas that come via this post.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `KeyComparator` that will order string arrays ignoring one element. So, `new KeyComparator(0)` will ignore element 0, and [A, B, C] will be equal to [D, B, C].

Split your keys into arrays as you've done, and store them in an `ArrayList<String[]>`

Sort this array N times, where N is the number of distinct components to your key, using the comparator (and varying the omitted column from 0 to N-1).

After each sort, the values that are sorted together (and compare equal using your comparator) should be grouped together.

However, what will you do with the following? You'd group the first two based on the first column, but group the last two using the second column.

```
A_B_C_D_E_F_G
B_B_C_D_E_F_G
B_C_C_D_E_F_G
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Re-post from the comment above but it could be in either group. The easiest way to deal with that would be to stick it in the first available group that it comes across.

Comment: Are you expecting me to write code for you? It isn't going to happen. If you do not understand how to translate this solution to code, ask questions. If it does not meet your needs, explain how your needs differ from what you originally asked.

Comment: huh?  I was stating what would happen if an entry can fall into more than one grouping

Answer (score 1):

I swear by algorithmic abstraction first.

ABSTRACTION

This grouping is of course only a partial ordering, so different solutions are possible.
Assuming every set has the same number of elements: N.

Every set has a relation to *neighbours* (having one element different) with (the index of) the different element.

Now we have categories, disjunct groups where (N - 1) elements are equals, and the remaining varies.
We also have single sets not fitting in those groups, and being able to elect 1 of N elements to vary. So they might form one of N groups.
These single sets are no neighbours, have at least 2 different elements.

Now adding a new set to your optimal data structures would need to do the following:
Check whether there is an existing category (N possibilities).

When found (case identical!) add it.

When not found, check single sets to form a group of 2 sets.

When found remove that singe set and introduce a new category.

When not found, add the set to the single sets.

IMPLEMENTATION

(Now if the number of elements were limited, one could use BitSets; you know, there are nice techniques to count the number of differing bits;
`diff = a ^ b; boolean naybour = (diff & (diff - 1)) == 0;`)

```
class Singleset { N elements } // What is called set, named so to avoid nameclash with Set
class Subset { N-1 elements; equals, hashcode, Comparable }
class Differings { set of elements }
Map<Subset, Differings> categories; // Reconstitues full Singlesets
Map<Subset, Singleset> singlesets; // Every single set has N-1 subsets, every value has N-1 keys
```

Now a Map < Subset, ...> can be more clever done with a tree on the elements. So you want:

```
class MapSubsetTo<T> { ... }
```

You can even just have one map to `DifferingsOrSingleSet`.